# Conection betwern internal servers in jump server

Tags: linux, networking, centos, devops

How can I make a connection between two internal server that can only be accessed via jump server?

For example, I have a Local PC, jump server, internal server A, and internal server B.

From Local PC, I can access A with the command: `ssh -J jump_server int_server_A`.

Now, I can access `int_server_A`'s terminal. How can I connect to `int_server_B` from `int_server_a`?

Comment: `ssh -J server ssh -J server server`. `int_server_B from int_server_b?` From itself?

Comment: @KamilCuk from ```int_server_a```, sorry. Edited

Answer (score 0):

You likely cannot, since the one main of the purposes of a jump server is to prevent direct connections.  By forcing all connections through the jump sever, admin/security tasks are easier.  If you can, to find out how you'll need to clarify:  What type of connection?  Can you ping between the two servers?  Are there any firewalls involved?  Etc.

Comment: I have a PHP script in `int_server_a`, and the script requires data from the database in `int_server_b`. Can A connect to Jump Server and then connect to B? What is the best practice?